# How to wait until data is loaded for showing this v-if condition correctly in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

It shows the no items found before the data is getting loaded., code looks like this:

```
<div class="columns" v-if="!products.length">
<p>No items found</p>
</div>
<div class="columns" v-if="products.length">
</div>

    async getProducts() {
      let res = await api.products.getProducts({
        products: products
      })
    },
```

Currently, it shows that no items found until the data is loading. How can I show that message only when data is loaded and it's empty?

Comment: `v-if="products.length > 0"`

Comment: Just check `products` is valid value first like `v-if="products && !products.length"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a variable `this.loading = false` and toggle after loaded.

```
data() {
  return { loaded = false }
},
methods: {
  async getProducts() {
    let res = await api.products.getProducts({
      products: products
    });
    this.loaded = true;
  },
}
```

In template.

```
<div class="columns" v-if="loaded && !products.length">
  <p>No items found</p>
</div>
<div class="columns" v-if="loaded && products.length"></div>
```