# Keep getting error "is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I keep getting the following error after binding my data components to the template. Any help would be appreciated.

script:

```js
data() {
  return {
    sireDetailsData: [],
    horse_show_name_prop:,
  }
},

async created () {
  const psireName = await this.sireName;

  console.log(psireName)

  try {
    const response = await sireDetails.fetchHorseIndex(psireName);

    this.sireDetailsData = response.data;

    try {
      this.horse_show_name_prop = this.sireDetailsData[0].horse_details[0].horse_show_name
    } catch (error) {
      this.horse_show_name_prop = undefined
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
},
```

template:

```html
<a-col
  :span="6"
  :md="6"
  align="middle"
  style="margin-right: 0px;"
  :horse_name="horse_show_name_prop"
>
  <p
    class="m-0 text-sm font-bold center"
    style="min-width: 0px;"
    v-if="horse_name !== undefined"
  >
    {{ horse_name }}%
  </p>

  <p
    class="m-0 text-sm font-bold center"
    style="min-width: 0px;"
    v-else
  >
    -
  </p>

  <a-tag
    class="ant-tag-primary font-semibold text-xs"
    style="min-width: 30px;margin-right: 0px;"
  >
    Win %
  </a-tag>
</a-col>
```

After making some live changes the data then loads in. It makes me think things are rendering out of order..

Comment: You probably need to wait for `fetchHorseIndex` to be done. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830489/17438890

Comment: If you use fetch to get your data, then please show your data structure, since we shouldn't guess it.

Comment: @Gabe I am waiting am i not?

Comment: @Kingswoop I think the rendering / mounting of the component does not wait for an await in the created hook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `horse_name` in data:

```
       data() {
            return {
                sireDetailsData: [],
                horse_show_name_prop:,
                horse_name: '', // Add horse_name here
            }
        },
```

Comment: Didnt seem to work, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kingswoop Looking at it again, I think you can just replace `{{ horse_name }}` with `{{ horse_show_name_prop }}`